# Need expanding chart where values per custom user text are counted

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

Sorry if my question is not clear but I'll explain in more detail here. 
I have a worksheet that calculates what percentage of a specific users events are mistakes. It figures this out by taking Defects / 1 + Check Ins + Checkouts.

[image: Worksheet]
The formulas I have currently are as follows:

Check Ins:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS('EH Data'!$M:$M,"timotwa*",'EH Data'!$A:$A,"CheckIn",'EH Data'!$L:$L,{"TRACTOR","BOX_TRUCK","VAN"}))
```

Check Outs:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS('EH Data'!$M:$M,"timotwa*",'EH Data'!$A:$A,"CheckOut",'EH Data'!$L:$L,{"TRACTOR","BOX_TRUCK","VAN"}))
```

Personal Defect Rate:

```
=IFERROR(F6/(D6+E6+1),0)
```

It checks data from two other sheets "EH Data" for the check in and check out entries and "Defects" for the defect entries.

I have to use wildcards because sometimes the username is in the form of an email and sometimes it is not and I want both counted and sometimes more than one username is in a cell.

The current formulas work, but I want to be able to add new rows and new users and not have to change every formula to put the custom username. I would want it to just automatically take it from the Username column and I can't seem to get this to work. I also want it to automatically fill down as rows are added.

TO REITERATE: I want the chart to work as it already does...I just want the usernames it is checking for to be pulled from the username column and NOT have to type it into every formula. In addition I need it to autofill the formulas as new rows are added.

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: replace `"timotwa*"` with `$C6&"*"`  That will take cae of using the name from column C6 as a wild card as the formulas are copied.  Having formulas fill in automatically as you add in more rows is another story which I will leave for someone else to answer

Comment: If your data is organized in an Excel table it will autofill the formulas on new rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I swore I tried just putting the cell in and it kept saying there was a problem with the formula but it's working great now!